How to update declared 'global variable' inside nested WHILE and FOR loops
In a Snowflake stored procedure,

I declared a 'global variable' inside the DECLARE block
then tried to update the value of the 'global variable' in nested WHILE and FOR loops inside the BEGIN block
inside the BEGIN block, the I have an outer WHILE loop, and an inner FOR loop
the updated variable inside my WHILE loop is not getting propagated to the next set of FOR LOOP iterations

Example 1 - For loop on each element in an array
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.PROCEDURENAME(
FIELD1 DATE,
FIELD2 DATE
)
RETURNS ARRAY
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
DECLARE
  COUNTER := 0;
  START_DT DATE;
  END_DT DATE;  
  WORKING_DT DATE;
  WORKING_DT_ARRAY := [];
  WITHIN_FORLOOP_ARRAY := [];
  ELEMENTS_FOR_FORLOOP_ARRAY := [1,2,3,4,5];
BEGIN
  WORKING_DT := $FIELD1;
  START_DT := $FIELD1;
  END_DT := $FIELD2;
  
  WHILE (WORKING_DT <= END_DT) DO
    FOR ELEMENT IN ELEMENTS_FOR_FORLOOP_ARRAY DO
      WITHIN_FORLOOP_ARRAY := ARRAY_APPEND(WITHIN_FORLOOP_ARRAY, WORKING_DT);

    END FOR;

    -- UPDATE WORKING_DT FOR NEXT WHILE LOOP ITERATION
      WORKING_DT_ARRAY := ARRAY_APPEND(WORKING_DT_ARRAY, WORKING_DT);
      WORKING_DT := DATEADD(DAY, 1, WORKING_DT);
      COUNTER := COUNTER+1;

  END WHILE;
  RETURN WITHIN_FORLOOP_ARRAY;
  -- RETURN WORKING_DT_ARRAY;

END;

-- Calling this procedure below returns
-- ['2024-01-01','2024-01-01','2024-01-01','2024-01-01','2024-01-01']
CALL DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.PROCEDURENAME('2024-01-01', '2024-01-02');

-- If I comment out 'RETURN WITHIN_FORLOOP_ARRAY;'
-- and uncomment 'RETURN WORKING_DT_ARRAY;'
-- Calling this procedure below returns
-- ['2024-01-01','2024-01-02']
CALL DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.PROCEDURENAME('2024-01-01', '2024-01-02');

So the question is,

Why is the updated value to the 'global variable' WORKING_DT inside the WHILE LOOP not getting passed into the FOR LOOP?
Why is the WHILE LOOP running for just 1 set of FOR LOOP iterations, when I am expecting it to run for 2 iterations - first for '2024-01-01', then for '2024-01-02'?

Example 2 - For loop on each table record
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.PROCEDURENAME(
FIELD1 DATE,
FIELD2 DATE
)
RETURNS ARRAY
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
DECLARE
  COUNTER := 0;
  START_DT DATE;
  END_DT DATE;  
  WORKING_DT DATE;
  WORKING_DT_ARRAY := [];
  WITHIN_FORLOOP_ARRAY := [];
  --ACTUAL USE CASE IS A TABLE TO LOOP ON
  TABLEA RESULTSET DEFAULT (SELECT FIELDA, FIELDB FROM DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.TABLEA);
BEGIN
  WORKING_DT := $FIELD1;
  START_DT := $FIELD1;
  END_DT := $FIELD2;
  
  WHILE (WORKING_DT <= END_DT) DO

    --LET'S SAY THERE ARE 5 RECORDS IN TABLEA
    FOR RECORDS IN TABLEA DO
      WITHIN_FORLOOP_ARRAY := ARRAY_APPEND(WITHIN_FORLOOP_ARRAY, WORKING_DT);

    END FOR;

    -- UPDATE WORKING_DT FOR NEXT WHILE LOOP ITERATION
      WORKING_DT_ARRAY := ARRAY_APPEND(WORKING_DT_ARRAY, WORKING_DT);
      WORKING_DT := DATEADD(DAY, 1, WORKING_DT);
      COUNTER := COUNTER+1;

  END WHILE;
  RETURN WITHIN_FORLOOP_ARRAY;
  -- RETURN WORKING_DT_ARRAY;

END;

-- Calling this procedure below returns
-- ['2024-01-01','2024-01-01','2024-01-01','2024-01-01','2024-01-01']
-- I am expecting
-- ['2024-01-01','2024-01-01','2024-01-01','2024-01-01','2024-01-01','2024-01-02','2024-01-02','2024-01-02','2024-01-02','2024-01-02']
CALL DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.PROCEDURENAME('2024-01-01', '2024-01-02');


If I grab the code and run it as block, with the input hardcoded:
DECLARE
  COUNTER number := 0;
  START_DT DATE;
  END_DT DATE;  
  WORKING_DT DATE;
  WORKING_DT_ARRAY := [];
  WITHIN_FORLOOP_ARRAY := [];
  ELEMENTS_FOR_FORLOOP_ARRAY := [1,2,3,4,5];
BEGIN
  WORKING_DT := '2024-01-01'::date;
  START_DT := '2024-01-01'::date;
  END_DT := '2024-01-02'::date;
  
  WHILE (WORKING_DT <= END_DT) DO
    FOR ELEMENT IN ELEMENTS_FOR_FORLOOP_ARRAY DO
      WITHIN_FORLOOP_ARRAY := ARRAY_APPEND(WITHIN_FORLOOP_ARRAY, WORKING_DT);

    END FOR;

    -- UPDATE WORKING_DT FOR NEXT WHILE LOOP ITERATION
      WORKING_DT_ARRAY := ARRAY_APPEND(WORKING_DT_ARRAY, WORKING_DT);
      WORKING_DT := DATEADD(DAY, 1, WORKING_DT);
      COUNTER := COUNTER+1;

  END WHILE;
  RETURN WITHIN_FORLOOP_ARRAY;
  --RETURN WORKING_DT_ARRAY;

END;

I get the results you expect:

And if I change those to varaibles:
set FIELD1 = '2024-01-01'::date;
set FIELD2 = '2024-01-02'::date;

DECLARE
  COUNTER number := 0;
  START_DT DATE;
  END_DT DATE;  
  WORKING_DT DATE;
  WORKING_DT_ARRAY := [];
  WITHIN_FORLOOP_ARRAY := [];
  ELEMENTS_FOR_FORLOOP_ARRAY := [1,2,3,4,5];
BEGIN
  WORKING_DT := $FIELD1;
  START_DT := $FIELD1;
  END_DT := $FIELD2;
  
  WHILE (WORKING_DT <= END_DT) DO
    FOR ELEMENT IN ELEMENTS_FOR_FORLOOP_ARRAY DO
      WITHIN_FORLOOP_ARRAY := ARRAY_APPEND(WITHIN_FORLOOP_ARRAY, WORKING_DT);

    END FOR;

    -- UPDATE WORKING_DT FOR NEXT WHILE LOOP ITERATION
      WORKING_DT_ARRAY := ARRAY_APPEND(WORKING_DT_ARRAY, WORKING_DT);
      WORKING_DT := DATEADD(DAY, 1, WORKING_DT);
      COUNTER := COUNTER+1;

  END WHILE;
  RETURN WITHIN_FORLOOP_ARRAY;
  --RETURN WORKING_DT_ARRAY;

END;

works as expected... lets try the function as you have it:
it also works as you seem to expect:


Thank you Simeon for your help with example 1.
For example 2 "For loop on each table record", would you have any idea how to resolve this?
